# Is there a threshold above which a matrix is ill-conditioned?

Tags: matrices, condition-number

My matrix has a condition number of $45.678$. Is it an ill-conditioned one?

Is there a threshold above which a matrix is ill-conditioned?

Comment: 45 is nothing. Condition numbers in the millions occur in many practical problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sharp boundary between "well-conditioned" and "ill-conditioned".  Your matrix is better-conditioned than one with $456.78$ but worse than one with $4.5678$.  Whether you would consider $45.678$ "ill-conditioned" might depend on the particular application.  But for most purposes I would think $45.678$ is not terribly bad.  It might cause you to lose up to $2$ significant figures of accuracy (i.e. your results may have $2$ fewer correct digits than the data), but assuming the data started out with much more than $2$ significant digits it won't make the results completely meaningless.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. In fact my solutions turned out to be meaningless as I need positive numbers ( I was calculating a quantity which has dimensions of time) and ended up with negative numbers. So I was wondering if that has anything to do with the conditioning of my matrix.